# How to write Generic Update Function for JSON object to update database selected columns

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am passing the following JSON object via POSTMAN. In my database I have one table called `T_Order`. I also have 3 columns `OrderId, ProductName, SKU`.

```
   {
    "api":
      {
        "NAME":"UPDATE",
        "QUERY":"UPDATE_ORDER"
      },
    "header":
   { 
        "OrderId":"3",
        "ProductName":"Samsung",
        "SKU":"87"
   },
   "lineItems":[
    {
        "OrderId":"3",
        "ProductName":"Samsung",
        "SKU":"87"
    }
   ]
}
```

Now, I want to create a generic Update function for updating my database columns. I have created a few lines of code for that. But I don't know how to write a generic Update function for it.

```cs
private void executeTableUpdate(string tableName, DBDataMessage requestObj, DBDataMessage responseObj)
{
    (Dictionary<string, string> colDefs, List<Dictionary<string, string>> colValues) = getLineItemsColumnDef(requestObj.lineItems);

    DataTable tbl = new DataTable();

    using (SqlConnection con = getNewDBConnection())
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    }
    Console.WriteLine("END: TEST");
}
```

My above method has 3 parameters. The `tableName` parameter takes the name of the table in our case `T_Order`. requestObj parameter takes api, header and lineitems. So now I want to complete this update function. Inside the using statement I can put update function. Remember all parameters are coming from the requestObj parameter.

Comment: EF Core and most ORMs already do this. If you try to do this on your own, your "generic" function will need to discover all the *specific* metadata information about the input type and table fields that EF Core already has

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I need to do this using ADO.NET

Comment: If you don't want to use EF Core you can use Dapper. The [Dapper.Contrib package](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper.Contrib) has `Insert` and `Update` methods that can insert/update tables from objects based on naming conventions.

Comment: `I need to do this using ADO.NET ` all ORMs, in fact, all data access libraries use ADO.NET. ORMs work *on top* of ADO.NET to do what you try to do by hand now - Map Objects to Relational tables and generate the SQL queries. That's what ORM means

Comment: BTW the JSON string you posted contains three different objects that should be stored in three different tables.